# Listview not scrolling smooth with viewflipper in every cell

Tags: android, listview, viewflipper

I am working on listview containing viewflipper inside every cell. Now viewflipper is tend to flip the image after every 2 seconds. In my adapter I have used the holder concept, but inside every holder there is a viewflipper which adds dynamic imageviews in it. I am sure that is the point which is not allowing listview to scroll smoothly. This is the function i am using to set images inside my holder:

```
viewflipper.removeAllViews();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams flip_pams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)(width*0.18), (int)(width*0.18));

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(pics)){
    String[] picarray= pics.split(", ");
    for(String pic: picarray){
        if(!dp.equals("")){
            ImageView image = new ImageView(con);
            image.setLayoutParams(flip_pams);
            imageLoader.displayImage(pic, image, options);

            viewflipper.addView(image);
        }
    }

    if(picarray.length>1){
        viewflipper.startFlipping();
    }
}
```

What can I do to improve it? Or is there any alternative to use instead of Viewflipper?
P.S: I know we should not set layoutparams inside holder of listview, secondly adding dynamic imageviews are also a mess. But I was not able to find any other alternative towards it.

Comment: Why are you not using _ViewPager_?

Comment: Because, requirement is to auto scroll the images inside each cell. Therefore, viewflipper has been used.

Comment: nops. Well it do, but when images per cell increases or if its HTC device. It's not smooth

Comment: You should make decent focusability false for listView when you touch on View flipper or you can call this _listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);_ on touch of view flipper

Comment: Viewflipper should flip automatically, not on touch of the viewflipper. Your said function will not interrupt that. Right?

Comment: Okay. So are using timer or Count down timer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110482/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-diksha-dhiman).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way;

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final ViewFlipper viewflipper;

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mLayout, null);

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.flipper = (ViewFlipper) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewConfFlipper1);
    viewHolder.flipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
    viewHolder.v2FieldName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLongName);
    viewHolder.button01 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);    
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    viewHolder.flipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
}


viewflipper = (ViewFlipper) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewConfFlipper1);

viewHolder.v2FieldName.setText(items.get(position).get("name"));        
viewHolder.button01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        viewflipper.showNext();
    }
});

return convertView;

}
```

Comment: But I have to add dynamic images on viewflipper, which might be different for each cell. How to do that?